# What is the best way to link individual element in an ArrayLists to another ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java

```
private ArrayList<String> professor = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<String> course = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<String> courseGroup = new ArrayList()
```

Professor Array list might contain:

```
["John","Dick","Harry"]
```

I want to link "John" to an ArrayList of courses that he might be teaching and in turn linking the course to an ArrayList of courseGroup as one course might have multiple classes. So it's like a record of what course Professor John is teaching and the course group he is assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

You need a class design for this work. For example

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    //getters and setters...
}

class Course {
    private String name;
    private Professor professor;
    private List<Person> students;
    //getters and setters...
}

class CourseGroup {
    private List<Course> courses;
    //getters and setters...
}
```

That could be a start for your program. It's up to you how to link the elements in your program. Here's a sample:

```
public class School {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person professor = new Professor();
        professor.setName("Harry");
        Course course = new Course();
        course.setName("Dick");
        course.setProfessor(professor);
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("Harry");
        course.setStudents(new ArrayList<Person>());
        course.getStudents().add(p);
        CourseGroup courseGroup = new CourseGroup();
        courseGroup.setCourses(new ArrayList<Course>());
        courseGroup.getCourses().add(course);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map`s (`HashMap<String, List<String>>`).

Or, better create classes (proper datastructures to handle it):

```
public class CourseGroup { }

public class Course {
    private List<CourseGroup> courseGroupList = new ArrayList<CourseGroup>();
}

public class Professor {
     private List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would typically represent each of these professors, courses and courseGroups as objects. A `Professor` object would then have a field `ArrayList<Course>` and so on.

To keep it concise however in this situation i would add 2 additional data structures:

```
Map<String, List<String>> profCourses = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
Map<String, List<String>> courseGroup = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Initiation could be done in the following way:

```
List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add("Math");
c.add("Biology");
profCourses.put("John", c);
```

Note that a lookup to see which courses John is teaching would be fast, but to see which  professors teach a certain course would not be as easy, iterating over the profCourses map would be required.

If a fast lookup in the other direction is desired you could use a different approach or add redundant data structures.

Comment: 'code'List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    x.add("Class 1");
    x.add("Class 2");
    courseGroup.put("Math",x);
'code'
Is this to correct way to further map "Math" in to the different class that "John" is teaching?